# Windows 10 displays strange symbols and restarts upon wake up

Tags: windows-10, sleep, reboot

I have HP ProDesk 490 G3 running Windows 10, it was running pretty well, but for the past month weird behavior is appearing. The screen now displays symbols on a blue screen:

[image]

This is what is happening before displaying this screen:

1. I lock the computer using shortcut Ctrl+L
2. Screen will turn off automatically during 20 second
3. -- computer is configured not to enter sleep
4. I will press random button after 20 minutes of inactivity to turn on the screen expecting login page to appear
5. Mentioned blue screen is displayed - symbols switch positions every 5 second or so, and are sometimes displayed differently, but general outlook stays the same. After about 15 seconds the computer will restart itself and before showing BIOS initialization it will stay everything black for about another 15 seconds.

It is not like this every time, sometimes it just work as expected.

Could you help me with this issue? I tried to search without any luck. Also reverse search of the image did not bring any results.

Comment: What does the event log say?

Comment: I have a low end Asus netbook running Windows 10 for testing. It would do strange things due to bad interactions in the power management system. I had to reinstall the OS twice because of bad drivers from Asus, and then a [automatic] Windows Update that was incompatible with the Asus hardware. I finally turned off the power manager.

Comment: prior to restart, there is **Error** saying "Filter Manager failed to attach to volume '\Device\HarddiskVolume14'.  This volume will be unavailable for filtering until a reboot.  The final status was 0xC03A001C."

Answer (score 0):

probably that's the backup volume, right? If so, try to manually disable VSS (Virtual Shadow Service) for that volume.

Comment: VSS is stopped and startup type is switched to "Manual".
How can I verify which volume is it?
But could be it, because I use windows backup to run at approximately that time.